# Decribing a  father's strict treatment of his children

Tags: phrase-requests

In the movie "The Sound of Music" the father, who was also a captain, was very strict with his children. He would always give them all kinds of commands and always used a whistle.

What's the best way to describe the way he was treating them?

1. He was treating them like in the army.
2. He was treating them like an officer treats his soldiers.
3. He was treating them like in the military.
4. He was treating them like soldiers.
5. `<Your option?`>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like: *He ran a regimented household, showing little affection for his children.*

*Regimented* is [defined as:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/regimented) strictly controlled; organized according to a strict, sometimes oppressive pattern. The word has a military sense to it, but is not exclusively a military term.

Comment: I like _regimented_ (that'd be my top choice; +1), but I'm not sure I agree with "showing little affection." It's been awhile since I've seen the movie, but it seems like the character treated his children the way he did, not because he was unaffectionate, but because, as a widowed military officer, that was the only way he seemed to know how to express his affection. I might suggest "_He ran a regimented household, instilling a strict, military discipline into his children_."

Comment: @J.R., Point taken, but it took Maria to help him "show" the children affection. Up to her arrival, he did not express affection for the children at all.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I remember more of his softer side, post-Maria. :^)

Answer (score 2):

He is a martinet ([a rigid military disciplinarian, or one who demands absolute adherence to forms and rules](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/martinet)).

Answer (score 1):

I like your second example.  Here is my suggestion:

> He was treating them like *[subordinates](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subordinate)*.